# Undocumented default values for sudoers' env_keep variable

Tags: ubuntu, sudo

I'm experiencing some strange behaviour.

My sudoers file is very short and looks like this :

```
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    mail_badpass
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

(Note, that's Ubuntu 13.10 with a backported 3.12 kernel)

With this sudoers, when I do `sudo env` I get almost all my unprivilegied user's environnement, including `http_proxy` and `https_proxy`.
Now if I append this line to the file, the environnement gets stripped as hell :

```
Defaults env_keep="http_proxy"
```

My bet is that there is a default value for `env_keep` that hold most of what's set in my environnement and that defining it without `env_keep+=` erases it.

Or that's a sudo bug I should submit ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After troubleshooting and discussing isue with [Bob](https://superuser.com/users/117590/bob) on the [Root Access chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access), we've found at that indeed, env_keep has undocumented default values.

Extract from sudo's manpage:

```
     -V          The -V (version) option causes sudo to print its version string and the ver‐
                 sion string of the security policy plugin and any I/O plugins.  If the invok‐
                 ing user is already root the -V option will display the arguments passed to
                 configure when sudo was built and plugins may display more verbose informa‐
                 tion such as default options.
```

```
user@host $: sudo sudo -V : 
[...]
Environment variables to preserve: 
XAUTHORIZATION 
XAUTHORITY 
TZ 
PS2 
PS1 
PATH 
LS_COLORS 
KRB5CCNAME 
HOSTNAME 
HOME 
DISPLAY 
COLORS
[...]
```

If you set env_keep without appending to it, it will override those values. So use `Defaults env_keep +="values"`